# How to handle authorization with Next.js 13

Tags: authentication, next.js, authorization, server-side-rendering, next.js13

**Initial situation:**
I have two server-side cookies (httponly) named *accessToken* and *refreshToken*. The payload looks like this:

```
{
   "user":{
      "firstname":"John",
      "lastname":"Doe",
      "roles":[
         "accounting",
         "supporter"
      ]
   }
}
```

**Goal:**
Handle server-side authorization with Next.js 13 (app folder-based). Some routes should be protected and only accessible to some users with specific roles.

**Example:**

- GET /login should be accessible to everyone
- GET /dashboard for authorized users only
- GET /accounting only for users with the *accounting* role
- GET /admin only for users with the role *admin*

Answer (score 1):

you could write a middleware. in next13 middleware file is in the same directory as package.json and it should be `middleware.js` (or .ts).

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  // get all the cookies
  let cookies = req.cookies.getAll();
  // read those cookies. based on cookies you decide which paths can be visited
  const isAuthorized="define logic if the the user authorized"
  console.log("req.pathname", req.nextUrl.pathname);
  const currentPath = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  if (currentPath==="/dashboard" && isAuthorized ){
    // you allow the user to visit this page
    return NextResponse.next()
  }
  // similarly add logic for other cases 
}
```